# Integrals of a Fourth order differential equation: Part A

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

Is it possible for us to get the value for integrals of a Fourth order differential equation in MMA.

I attach the code that i have used in MMA:

```
eqn = 4 y''''[x] - 4 y''[x] + y[x] - 1;
sol1 = DSolve[{eqn == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y'[1] == 0, 
    y''[1] == 0}, y[x], x];
y[x] = y[x] /. sol1;
eqn1 = (y'[x])^2 + (y''[x])^2 + (y[x] - 1)^2/4;
yys = Integrate[eqn1, {x, 0, 1}];
N[yys]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine if you change `y[x] =` to `y[x_] =`

```
Clear[y]

eqn = 4 y''''[x] - 4 y''[x] + y[x] - 1;
sol1 = DSolve[{eqn == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y'[1] == 0, 
    y''[1] == 0}, y[x], x];
y[x_] = y[x] /. sol1[[1]];
eqn1 = (y'[x])^2 + (y''[x])^2 + (y[x] - 1)^2/4;
yys = Integrate[eqn1, {x, 0, 1}];
N[yys]

(* 0.249227 *)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, your answer is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that using `y[x] = ...` will not teach Mathematica what y'[x] should be:

```
Clear[y]
eqn = 4 y''''[x]-4 y''[x]+y[x]-1;
sol1 = DSolve[{eqn==0,y[0]==0,y'[0]==0,y'[1]==0,y''[1]==0},y[x],x];
y[x] = y[x] /. sol1;
y[x] //Short
y'[x]
```

> {(E^(-(x/Sqrt[2])) (2 E^Sqrt[2]-2 Sqrt[2] E^Sqrt[2]+<<39>>+3 <<2>> x+E^(2 Sqrt[2]+<<1>>) x))/((-2+Sqrt[2]+2 E^Sqrt[2]+Sqrt[2] E^Sqrt[2]) (1+E^(2 Sqrt[2])))}
>
> y'[x]

*(Another issue is the presence of the extraneous {} around the solution)*

Instead, I think it's much simpler to use [`DSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue) and to also use a different symbol (`yy` vs. `y`) for the result:

```
Clear[y]
eqn = 4 y''''[x]-4 y''[x]+y[x]-1;
yy = DSolveValue[{eqn==0,y[0]==0,y'[0]==0,y'[1]==0,y''[1]==0}, y, x];
eqn1 = (y'[x])^2+(y''[x])^2+(y[x]-1)^2/4 /. y->yy;
Integrate[eqn1, {x, 0, 1}]
```

> (-10 + 4 Cosh[Sqrt[2]] + 3 Sqrt[2] Sinh[Sqrt[2]] - 7 Sqrt[2] Tanh[Sqrt[2]] + 
>    2 Sech[Sqrt[2]] (7 - 6 Sech[Sqrt[2]] + 3 Sqrt[2] Tanh[Sqrt[2]]))/(-2 + 
>    6 Cosh[Sqrt[2]] + 4 Sqrt[2] Sinh[Sqrt[2]])

Comment: thanks a lot, your answer is also very helpful!