# Integrals of a Fourth order differential equation: Part B

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I want to continue this topics ([enter link description here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186156/integrals-of-a-fourth-order-differential-equation-is-not-possible)):

Is it possible for us to get the value for integrals of a Fourth order differential equation ***(But) which includes a constant parameter***?

I attach the code that i have used in MMA:

```
Clear[y]
Clear[fac]

eqn = 4 y''''[x] fac - 4 y''[x] + y[x] - 1;
sol1 = DSolve[{eqn == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y'[1] == 0, 
   y''[1] == 0}, y[x], x]
y[x_] = y[x] /. sol1[[1]]
eqn1 = (y'[x])^2 + fac (y''[x])^2 + (y[x] - 1)^2/4;
yys = Integrate[eqn1, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> fac > 0]
yys = yys /. fac -> 1
```

If we define fac := 1 in the first line, it works fine (see PART A) in MMA.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: However, it works for second order differential equation which includes a constant parameter in MMA!

Comment: What are the limitations on the parameter `fac`?

Comment: @Alex Trounev how about [0.000001 3000]?

Comment: @AlexTrounev for 2.Order, I don't need to define limitations for "fac"

Comment: @AlexTrounev Clear[y]
Clear[fac]

eqn = 4 y''[x] fac + y[x] - 1;
sol1 = DSolve[{eqn == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[1] == 0}, y[x], x]
y[x_] = y[x] /. sol1[[1]]
eqn1 = fac (y'[x])^2 + (y[x] - 1)^2/4;
yys = Integrate[eqn1, {x, 0, 1}]

Comment: Is it possible to assume fac> 0?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, sure we can do

Comment: @AlexTrounev, , {fac, 0, Infinity} doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, as you suggested, I changed the codes, but it still not works...

Comment: @AlexTrounev , I have checked again, I am sure that, we can not give the value for "fac", as sqrt(1-sqrt) not possible, other think is if we define "fac" =0 in the first line, it can be solved, I hope that is not the bug in solver.

Comment: Certainly, this integral can be evaluated, although the special case `fac = 1` must be treated separately.

Comment: So, what is your question?  Clearly, this problem can be solved with Mathematica.  But, you cannot simply set `fac -> 1` in the final line of code.

Comment: After defining `y[x]`, if you say `y[x]/.fac->1` it blows up.  But if you take the limit,

Comment: @BillWatts , I will give a try, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shorten the record, we put `f = fac`, solve the equation in general form with three indefinite coefficients `C[1],C[2],C[3]`, calculate the integral, then determine the coefficients and substitute into the integral expression. Then all the expressions are observable, and the special case f = 1 can be studied separately.

```
eqn = 4 D[y[x], {x, 4}]*f - 4 y''[x] + y[x] - 1;
sol1 = DSolve[{eqn == 0, y[0] == 0}, y[x], x]
Y[x_] = y[x] /. sol1[[1]]
eqn1 = (Y'[x])^2 + f*(Y''[x])^2 + (Y[x] - 1)^2/4;
yys = Integrate[eqn1, {x, 0, 1}]

s1 = Flatten[
  Solve[{Y'[0] == 0, Y'[1] == 0, Y''[1] == 0}, {C[1], C[2], C[3]}]];
yf = yys /. s1;
Plot[Abs[yf], {f, .01, 3}, AxesLabel -> {"f", "yys"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: fig1]

The special case `f = 1`

```
eqn = 4 D[y[x], {x, 4}] - 4 y''[x] + y[x] - 1;
sol1 = DSolve[{eqn == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y'[1] == 0, 
   y''[1] == 0}, y[x], x];
Y[x_] = y[x] /. sol1[[1]];
eqn1 = (Y'[x])^2 + (Y''[x])^2 + (Y[x] - 1)^2/4;
yys = Integrate[eqn1, {x, 0, 1}]
 (-10 + 4 Cosh[Sqrt[2]] + 3 Sqrt[2] Sinh[Sqrt[2]] - 
   7 Sqrt[2] Tanh[Sqrt[2]] + 2 Sech[Sqrt[2]] (7 - 6 Sech[Sqrt[2]] + 3 Sqrt[2] Tanh[Sqrt[2]]))/(-2 + 6 Cosh[Sqrt[2]] + 4 Sqrt[2] Sinh[Sqrt[2]])
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your answer! But I donot know, why we define the Bcs later, (Y'[0] == 0, Y'[1] == 0, Y''[1] == 0) not in eq. sol1 ?

Comment: This is a symbolic computation problem. Mathematica finds a solution with bcs in the form of a very long expression, which, when calculating the integral, becomes even longer and no longer fits in memory. Therefore, there is a hang for a long time, and the end result is not visible.

Comment: @AlexnTrounev, okay, good to know this part about MMA!

Answer (score 1):

After solving for `y[x]` if you do `y[x]/.fac->1`, it blows up.  But if you use  `Limit[y[x],fac->1]`, it works fine.  You can also try

```
Table[Integrate[eqn1, {x, 0, 1}], {fac, .1, 2, .1}] // Chop
(*{0.244558,0.246739,0.247674,0.248192,0.248522,0.24875,0.248917,0.249045,0.249145,-4.56719*10^46,0.249294,0.249351,0.249399,0.24944,0.249477,0.249508,0.249537,0.186523,0.249584,0.249604}*)
```

where you can see the value at `fac = 1` blows up showing that to be a special case.  The value at `fac = 1.8` also looks suspicious, but that is due to precision.  Obviously setting fac before the calculations start works fine.

MMa successfully calculates yys with your code, but it is huge and finding the limit takes forever.  After simplification, the limit is found reasonably quickly.

```
yys = yys // Simplify;

Limit[yys, fac -> 1]
(* (-1 - 2 (5 + 2 Sqrt[2]) E^Sqrt[2] - (11 + 14 Sqrt[2]) E^(
  2 Sqrt[2]) + (44 Sqrt[2] - 47) E^(
  4 Sqrt[2]) + (122 - 92 Sqrt[2]) E^(5 Sqrt[2]) + (11 - 6 Sqrt[2]) E^(
  6 Sqrt[2]))/(Sqrt[2] ((Sqrt[2] - 3) E^Sqrt[2] - 1)^2 (1 + E^(
   2 Sqrt[2]))^2) *)

% // N
(* 0.249227 *)
```

Comment: in this case, I want to give the value of fac to yys, not to y[x] ....

Comment: even it is not very good idea to define in the final line for the value of fac, okay, just fine now!

Comment: But if `y[x]` blows up for `fac = 1`, `yys` will also.  By taking the limit you can use that value to work the rest of the problem and find `yys` for `fac = 1`.  It is possible that you could take the limit of `yys` at the end, but the result is huge and I have not tried to run it all night to see if I get an answer or run out of memory.  Getting values for `yys` with other values of `fac` will not necessarily require using limits.